# Running a github action after travis CI succeed

Tags: yaml, travis-ci, github-actions

I want to somehow only run a Github action on a PR if the travis CI succeeds. I suppose this can extrapolate to any other sort of CI.

Currently the system runs like this

```
1) submit PR
2) Travis CI & Action run at the same time
```

But I want this flow:

```
1) submit PR
2) Travis CI runs
  success: run Action
  failure: don't run Action
```

I have tried implementing [run-travis-yml](https://github.com/ktomk/run-travis-yml) which basically just lets me run the build script for the Travis CI ahead of the next step in the Action; however, I guess that the actual CI is asynchronous and so it will always succeed purely based on if it builds.

How can I run a given action after a separate check succeeds or fails?

By the way, [this code is public](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/3482)

Comment: Have you tried a dispatch from travis to github action as the very last step of the travis build? (API endpoint call; ref https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

Comment: yeah that's possible but not super clean. Also, if I do that how would I maintain the same github context in the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

`https://api.github.com/repos/ethereum/EIPs/commits/<ref>/statuses` for some reason only sees the statuses of my 3rd party CI checks. So even if other tests fail it only considers the CI ones.

So I used this property to check it every 30 seconds and then abort if an error occurs; here's the code for that:

```js
// HACK (alita): check the CI status and only continue if the CI is successful
const checkCIStatus = async () => {
  const Github = getOctokit(GITHUB_TOKEN);
  const pr = await requirePr()
  const status = await Github.repos.getCombinedStatusForRef({
    owner: context.repo.owner,
    repo: context.repo.repo,
    ref: pr.head.ref
  }).then(res => res.data.state)

  console.log(`status is '${status}'...`)
  if (status === "failure") {
    setFailed("CI checks failed; bot can only merge if CI checks pass")
    throw "CI checks failed; bot can only merge if CI checks pass"
  }

  return status === "success";
}

export const pauseInterval = (checker, next, timeout) => async () => {
  const status = await checker();
  if (!status) {
    setTimeout(pauseInterval(checker, next, timeout), timeout);
  } else {
    return next()
  }
}

// only runs the bot if the CI statuses pass; checks every 30 seconds
export const main = pauseInterval(checkCIStatus, _main, CHECK_STATUS_INTERVAL)
```

output from success

```sh
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
status is 'success'...
<normal action outputs>
```

output from failed checks

```sh
status is 'pending'...
status is 'pending'...
(node:1603) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CI checks failed; bot can only merge if CI checks pass
status is 'failure'...
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1603) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1603) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is notably only really possible in a custom action, but you could probably create a simple action / js file that could do the same behavior and be treated as an action before the given action. If you had that, and this failed / succeeded on success or error then you could conditionally call your action within the Github yaml script.